# Is the use of "who" correct in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns

> "The Turk is chess engine **who** can interact with user interfaces
>   which support Winboard protocol at the moment"

I feel that *which* can be used instead of *who* but I'm not sure. If that's not correct what should I use instead of *who*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very unclear sentence, for many reasons, one of which is the use of *who*.

First, the noun phrase *chess engine*, as a count predicate noun, needs an **indefinite** article:

> *The Turk is **a** chess engine*

and the noun phrase *Winboard protocol* needs a **definite** article:

> *supports **the** Winboard protocol.*

Second, you use a [stacked relative clause construction](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/fillmore.html) with **two** *Wh-* words, which is bad style -- repeating a grammatical word should carry extra information, or there's no point to it and it just makes work for everybody. It would be much better to omit one of the *Wh-* words (this won't work here because both are subjects and only non-subject relative pronouns can be deleted), or to substitute *that* for one of them,

> *a chess engine **that** can interact with user interfaces which support the Winboard protocol*
>
> *a chess engine which can interact with user interfaces **that** support the Winboard protocol*

or to reduce one or both of the relatives to a participle:

> *a chess engine that can interact with user interfaces **supporting** the Winboard protocol*
>
> *a chess engine **interacting** with user interfaces that support the Winboard protocol*
>
> *a chess engine **interacting** with user interfaces **supporting** the Winboard protocol*

Finally, the temporal phrase *at the moment* is sitting at the very end of the sentence, after both relative clauses, and it's not clear what clause it refers to. Does it mean

- it interacts only with interfaces that **currently** support Winboard (but not others)
- it interacts with the **current** interfaces that support Winboard (but not the old ones)
- it **currently** interacts with interfaces that support Winboard (but changes are planned)
- ... etc?

So, put *at the moment* close to what it modifies.

Oh, and ***don't*** use *who*. *Who* is for people, not programs, no matter how good they are.

Comment: "Who is for people, not programs..." ... What about [fake simulacra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Turk)?

Comment: That's the Turing test. This is the wrong stack exchange for that.

Comment: Is this correct too? "a chess engine **that** can interact with user interfaces **and supports** the Winboard protocol"

Comment: Yes, it's correct, but it doesn't necessarily mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I find the sentence difficult to understand, perhaps because I am not familiar with the subject. If *Turk* is simply the name of the chess engine, then the relative pronoun has to be *which*, not *who*, but you could also introduce the clause with *that*. In any case, I think you need the indefinite article, *a*, before *chess engine*.

Answer (score -2):

If you use "which", you would imply that there is one or more chess engines like "Turk". But if it is unprecedented, you might use "who" instead of "which". In my opinion, in that sentence, the word "engine" may cause to alter the usage of "who".

Comment: Nah. The "who/which" distinction doesn't turn on how many others there are like it - it's all about whether "The Turk" can reasonably be anthropomorphised (spoken of as a human being).

Comment: I really wanted to emphasize your opinion. Look at my last sentence  again...

Comment: As others have said, and as you obviously recognise, the word "engine" seriously discourages us from using "who" here. All I'm saying is it's irrelevant whether "The Turk" is the only engine of its kind, or if there are dozens of engines like it. It's still an "it", so we would normally use "that" or "which" to refer to it.

Comment: I want to say that "which" means there is a pool and there are lots of things in that pool. You emphasize a particular thing from that pool, and use "which". It would be weird if we use "which" for only one thing. But, "who" seems to be true with respect to its usage,because engine has some properties and is able to calculate something in itself. So, it might be reasonable if we assimilate it to a "human".

Comment: There are some unusual circumstances where you can use "who" for an animal, or even a machine, but I don't think "The Turk" (an 18th century *fake* chess-playing machine) would really qualify. But your point about whether "which" implies there must be at least *some* other similar things "which don't" is interesting. I honestly don't know the answer to that one - so if you don't ask it as a question here I might do so myself!